# Non-static method ::read_file() cannot be called statically

Tags: php, static-methods

This is an old script made for php5 and it won't run on php 8 so I'm trying to update it but I get this error:

```
Non-static method fileio::read_file() cannot be called statically in scripts\sb_fileio.php:13 Stack trace: #0 scripts\sb_config.php(156): sb_read_file('config/config.t...') #1 index.php(18): read_config() #2 {main} thrown in \scripts\sb_fileio.php on line 13
```

These are the functions involved:

```
function read_config ( ) {
    // Read config information from file.
    //
    global $blog_config;

    $blog_config = array();

    // LOAD CONFIG INFORMATION
    $contents = sb_read_file( CONFIG_DIR.'config.txt' );
    if ( $contents ) {
      $temp_configs = explode('|', $contents);
      $config_keys = array(   'blog_title',
/////
```

and

```
function sb_read_file( $filename ) {
        return fileio::read_file($filename);
    }
```

I tried by changing to:

```
static function read_config ( )
```

but then it throws this error:

```
unexpected identifier "read_config", expecting "("
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error complaints about calling `read_file()` statically, while you're changing `read_config()`?

Comment: I did try to change that too and I got the same error:  `function sb_read_file( $filename ) {
  return static fileio::read_file($filename);
 }`

Comment: Please read the [manual about static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php). 1. If you want to call the method `read_file($filename);` statically, then it's _that_ class method which needs to be declared static: `static function read_file($filename) { ... }`. The last error (about `read_config()`) needs context. Is `read_config()` a class method or a an ordinary function (not in a class)? You can't declare functions as static, only class methods and properties.

Comment: I didnt write the script so its very hard to pinpoint the culprit like that.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: What is `fileio` in this context? You're also updating the wrong function as `static` - it's not a hierarchy thing. Can you track down where `fileio` is relevant/what it is? Your problem will most likely stem from there

Comment: Yes, I found where to add the "static" part that is missing.